# Adding ArrayList elements efficiently

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

How would I shorten this?

```
int[] a1 = {2, 0, 1, 4, 3};
int[] a2 = {3, 1, 2, 0, 4};
int[] a3 = {4, 2, 3, 1, 0}; 
int[] a4 = {0, 3, 4, 2, 1};
int[] a5 = {1, 4, 0, 3, 2};
ArrayList<int[]> array = new ArrayList<int[]>();
array.add(a1);
array.add(a2);
array.add(a3);
array.add(a4);
array.add(a5);
```

Comment: Don't use an array list? just use int[][]?

Comment: Short code != Efficient code.

Comment: Looks like a problem where I'd go straight for a 'matrix' class with a single array (more so I don't have to manage all the nested array weirdness rather than the premature optimisation).

Answer (score 3):

```
List<int[]> ints = Arrays.asList(new int[][]{{2, 0, 1, 4, 3},
                                             {3, 1, 2, 0, 4},
                                             {4, 2, 3, 1, 0},
                                             {0, 3, 4, 2, 1},
                                             {1, 4, 0, 3, 2}});
```

is one way.

**Edit**: bmargulies rightly pointed out that the resulting `List` is not necessarily an `ArrayList`; if one is needed, you can then copy the elements into a new one.

Comment: This is Java 1.4, yes?  In Java 5+ you'd just list the elements: Arrays.asList({1,2,3},{4,5,6});  The resulting list is fixed-length.

Comment: @bmargulies: not necessarily, but the conversion is simple enough.  I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: @Michael Brewer-Davis: I'd think that would work, but for some reason it gives a compile-time error.

Comment: Seems like it's because there's nothing to cause creation of an array object.

Comment: `Arrays.asList` does return an `ArrayList`, but it is a `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList` not a `java.util.ArrayList` (nice naming). :)

Comment: Seems that YuppieNetworking has shown the best syntax for asList() (better than Arrays.asList(new int[]{1,2,3}, new int[]{4,5,6});)  All in all, I'd stick with the original or Kevin Connor's and not worry about asList().

Answer (score 2):

[K.I.S.S.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle):

```
ArrayList<int[]> array = new ArrayList<int[]>();
array.add(new int[] { 2, 0, 1, 4, 3 });
array.add(new int[] { 3, 1, 2, 0, 4 });
array.add(new int[] { 4, 2, 3, 1, 0 });
array.add(new int[] { 0, 3, 4, 2, 1 });
array.add(new int[] { 1, 4, 0, 3, 2 });
```

It does the same thing as the old code, is shorter, and performs fine.

Answer (score 0):

With `Arrays.asList`

```
    int[][] a = {
            {2, 0, 1, 4, 3},
            {3, 1, 2, 0, 4},
            {4, 2, 3, 1, 0}, 
            {0, 3, 4, 2, 1},
            {1, 4, 0, 3, 2}
    };
    List<int[]> arr = Arrays.asList(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want 'array' to contain the same information? Something like:

```
int[][] a = {{2, 0, 1, 4, 3}, {3, 1, 2, 0, 4}, {3, 1, 2, 0, 4}, {0, 3, 4, 2, 1}, {1, 4, 0, 3, 2}};
    ArrayList<int[]> array = new ArrayList<int[]>();
    for(int[] i: a)
        array.add(i);
```

is shorter than what you posted. Are you trying to shorten the declaration of the variables a1-5, or the repetitive calls to add, or both?